# Excluding records from subquery

Tags: mysql

I have a query that I need to remove specific records from another table.
Here is the query I have.
The below code selects all the app info for all groups the user is in.

```
SELECT   app_name,
         ifnull(max(priv_access), 'N') as priv_access,
         ifnull(max(priv_insert),'N') as priv_insert,
         ifnull(max(priv_delete),'N') as priv_delete,
         ifnull(max(priv_update),'N') as priv_update,
         ifnull(max(priv_export),'N') as priv_export,
         ifnull(max(priv_print),'N') as priv_print
      FROM prismreporting_sec_groups_apps
      WHERE group_id IN
          (SELECT
           group_id
       FROM
           prismreporting_sec_users_groups 
       WHERE
           login = 'kdriscoll')
       group by app_name
```

I want to now exclude any records in another table for that user.
I have two fields called login and app_name
the name of the table is prismreporting_sec_removeuser_apps
and this is the select I was trying to use

```
select app_name from prismreporting_sec_removeuser_apps where login = 'kdriscoll'
```

I really dont know what way (if any ) I can do this...
Can someone help?

Thanks in advance

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
    *where not in* clause :

```
SELECT   app_name,
     ifnull(max(priv_access), 'N') as priv_access,
     ifnull(max(priv_insert),'N') as priv_insert,
     ifnull(max(priv_delete),'N') as priv_delete,
     ifnull(max(priv_update),'N') as priv_update,
     ifnull(max(priv_export),'N') as priv_export,
     ifnull(max(priv_print),'N') as priv_print
  FROM prismreporting_sec_groups_apps
  WHERE group_id IN
      (SELECT
       group_id
   FROM
       prismreporting_sec_users_groups 
   WHERE
       login = 'kdriscoll'
and app_name not in 
(select app_name from prismreporting_sec_removeuser_apps 
where login = 'kdriscoll')
   group by app_name
```